# Determining the size of a merged area

Tags: excel, vba, office-2003

Right, before we get off about merged cells, I hate them too, but I've to deal with them anyway. I cannot change anything about that now or in the future. As much as I would like to ;)

Say I have some merged cells, I need to determine the amount of cells it spans.
Say A1:A4 are merged, then I need to have the number of merged cells, 4, returned.
Is  there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
Dim r As range
Dim i As Integer
    Set r = range("A1")
    i = r.CurrentRegion.Count
```

This will give A1:A4 as 4, A1:B4 as 8.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct.  If I merge A1:A4 and put a value in there.  Then I put a value in A5, CurrentRegion will return 5 even though there are only 4 merged cells.

Comment: So you didn't want to know the number of cells that were merged?  You wanted to know the number of contiguous cells with a value?

Comment: This didn't work for me with MS Excel 2007 on an `.xls` (i.e. not `.xlsx`) sheet. However using `.MergeArea.Count` instead, like Dick suggested, works fine.

Answer (score 13):

```
ActiveCell.MergeArea.Count
```