# Determine range encompassed by merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

Given a merged cell in Excel, is it possible to determine with VBA what rows the merged cell includes? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673171/determining-the-size-of-a-merged-area), but that only returns the number of cells included in the merged cell; I need its start and stop cells (or, in my case, just the *row* the merged cell starts and stops in; the cell is always only one cell wide).

For example, given that cells `A1:A5` are merged, and I know that cell `A3` is included in that merge, I'd like to be able to programatically get `1` (start) and `5` (stop). I would greatly prefer not to `select` the cells, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("YourRange")

    With r.MergeArea
        MsgBox "Merged Range start row = " & .Row & vbNewLine & _
            "Merge Range stop row = " & .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
    End With

End Sub
```